# XSL Grouping Problem

Tags: xslt

Using XSLT 1.0 - I have the following xml and I an trying to perform the following

- Group By the first Field where id="1923" if the value attribute is the same
- and average all the fields with id="3095" using the value attribute
- and average all the fields with id="3095" using the value attribute

---

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Trans.xsl"?>
 <Results>
  <List count="6">
   <Record contentId="1017835" finalFlag="True" levelId="" moduleId="152" primarySortId="" secondarySortId="" parentId="0" row="1" parentRow="" >
    <Field id="1923" type="1" value="Test 1"></Field>
    <Field id="3095" type="4" valueID="3809" value="1" parentId="3809" parentName="5" ></Field>
    <Field id="3096" type="4" valueID="3809" value="1" parentId="3809" parentName="5" ></Field>
   </Record>
   <Record contentId="1017828" finalFlag="True" levelId="" moduleId="152" primarySortId="" secondarySortId="" parentId="0" row="2" parentRow="" >
    <Field id="1923" type="1" value="Test 2"></Field>
    <Field id="3095" type="4" valueID="729" value="2" parentId="729" parentName="2" ></Field>
    <Field id="3096" type="4" valueID="3809" value="5" parentId="3809" parentName="5" ></Field>
   </Record>
   <Record contentId="1017978" finalFlag="True" levelId="" moduleId="152" primarySortId="" secondarySortId="" parentId="0" row="3" parentRow="" >
    <Field id="1923" type="1" value="Test 3"></Field>
    <Field id="3095" type="4" valueID="3808" value="4" parentId="3808" parentName="4" ></Field>
    <Field id="3096" type="4" valueID="3808" value="4" parentId="3808" parentName="4" ></Field>
   </Record>
   <Record contentId="1035463" finalFlag="True" levelId="" moduleId="152" primarySortId="" secondarySortId="" parentId="0" row="4" parentRow="" >
    <Field id="1923" type="1" value="Test 2"></Field>
    <Field id="3095" type="4" valueID="3808" value="4" parentId="3808" parentName="4" ></Field>
    <Field id="3096" type="4" valueID="730" value="3" parentId="730" parentName="3" ></Field>
   </Record>
   <Record contentId="1017985" finalFlag="True" levelId="" moduleId="152" primarySortId="" secondarySortId="" parentId="0" row="5" parentRow="" >
    <Field id="1923" type="1" value="Test 1"></Field>
    <Field id="3095" type="4" valueID="113690" value="10" parentId="113690" parentName="10" ></Field>
    <Field id="3096" type="4" valueID="113690" value="10" parentId="113690" parentName="10" ></Field>
   </Record>
   <Record contentId="1017835" finalFlag="True" levelId="" moduleId="152" primarySortId="" secondarySortId="" parentId="0" row="6" parentRow="" >
    <Field id="1923" type="1" value="Test 1"></Field>
    <Field id="3095" type="4" valueID="3809" value="5" parentId="3809" parentName="5" ></Field>
    <Field id="3096" type="4" valueID="3809" value="5" parentId="3809" parentName="5" ></Field>
   </Record>
  </List>
 </Results>
```

Trying to produce the following using trans.xsl:

```
<Records>
 <Data>
  <Text1923>Test 1</Text1923>
  <Avg3095>5.33</Avg3095>
  <Avg3096>5.33</Avg3096>
 </Data>
 <Data>
  <Text1923>Test 2</Text1923>
  <Avg3095>3</Avg3095>
  <Avg3096>4</Avg3096>
 </Data>
 <Data>
  <Text1923>Test 3</Text1923>
  <Avg3095>4</Avg3095>
  <Avg3096>4</Avg3096>
 </Data>
</Records>
```

Comment: And what technology are you using to work with your XML? Xsl? Java? .NET? Something else?

Comment: I am using .NET 2.0 and trying to transform the above xml to generate a dashboard showing key text and averages

Comment: The transformation is based on an xsl document that I am trying to create

Comment: The XML is generated dynamically via a web service and the only fixed data attributes are the ids and types in the first xml structure so I can't really depend on the value attribute to test its content since it is changing

Comment: Good Question (+1)! See my answer for a complete and efficient solution. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here is a simple XSLT 1.0 solution using the Muenchian Grouping Method**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:key name="kFieldById" match="Field"
  use="@id"/>

 <xsl:key name="kField1923"
  match="Field[@id='1923']" use="@value"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <Records>
    <xsl:for-each select=
    "key('kFieldById', '1923')
         [generate-id()
         =
          generate-id(key('kField1923',
                          @value
                          )
                           [1]
                      )
          ]
    ">
     <Data>
         <Text1923>
           <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
         </Text1923>

         <xsl:variable name="vSubfield3095" select=
           "key('kField1923',@value)
                         /../Field[@id='3095']
           "/>

         <xsl:variable name="vSubfield3096" select=
           "key('kField1923',@value)
                         /../Field[@id='3096']
           "/>

         <Avg3095>
           <xsl:value-of select=
            "sum($vSubfield3095/@value)
            div
             count($vSubfield3095)
            "/>
         </Avg3095>

         <Avg3096>
           <xsl:value-of select=
            "sum($vSubfield3096/@value)
            div
             count($vSubfield3096)
            "/>
         </Avg3096>
     </Data>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </Records>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document, the wanted, correct resul is produced**:

```
<Records>
   <Data>
      <Text1923>Test 1</Text1923>
      <Avg3095>5.333333333333333</Avg3095>
      <Avg3096>5.333333333333333</Avg3096>
   </Data>
   <Data>
      <Text1923>Test 2</Text1923>
      <Avg3095>3</Avg3095>
      <Avg3096>4</Avg3096>
   </Data>
   <Data>
      <Text1923>Test 3</Text1923>
      <Avg3095>4</Avg3095>
      <Avg3096>4</Avg3096>
   </Data>
</Records>
```

Comment: @Wail: Glad it was useful. How about upvoting + accepting the answer? :)

Comment: Accpeted answer and not sure why it does not allow me to up the vote for you . ANy ideas and I will be glad to up the vote perhapse I do not have enough points to vote?